# phpMyAdmin - doesn't show select results

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

My phpMyAdmin installation seems to be working just fine. I can handle databases and tables and insert datasets in tables.

*But* I cannot see the datasets in the tables. If I try to let it show the datasets by selecting "Browse" in the table-navigation, I get the following message:

```
Showing rows 0 - 0 ( 1 total, Query took 0.0061 sec)
```

BUT the table remains empty and no error messages appear.

I can get the data using php.

- PHP Version: 5.2.6
- MySQL Version: 5.0.45
- phpMyAdmin Version: 3.5.3

Comment: lol....its there bro.  PEBKAC.

Comment: Then chances are you are browsing the wrong database. If phpMyAdmin manages to connect to a database, but shows no data, you are either in the wrong view, or there is indeed no data in the table.

Comment: @Pekka There is data. PHPMyAdmin shows that it is showing 1 record.

Comment: Check your PHP script too. Does it show data with some checks or conditions?

Comment: Does the record contain values? If you have a record with only NULL values or empty strings, it may look like there is no record.

Comment: What kind of a SELECT are you doing? Maybe you have some condition in phpMyAdmin that is preventing the 1 record from being shown.

Comment: no, the select returns the number of rows correctly. So the database is right. AND I don't give the SQL statement, it's the one from phpMyAdmin so it should work...

Comment: Just to add to the above might I suggest you do a couple of inserts either via the sql tab or via the insert tab then repeat your browse you might also like to add a screen print of the result. We could then point you in the right direction.

Comment: I did try it with other tables and more inserts. The creation works fine. Data is in the database. I can get the data using my own php script. Still won't show in phpMyAdmin although number of rows is returned correctly!

Comment: @GolezTrol: Yes, I realized that later and removed the part with `@` from my comment.

Comment: no ideas? @bigman: Possible, but just the realization doesn't help me much...

Comment: @Rubinho So hit it from another tool and see if that works. Hell, even try command line.

Comment: @bigman: I did it, my own script gets me the data. BUT I cannot change or delete any dataset when it is not shown in this table. I could make my own interface but then I wouldn't need phpMyAdmin. It would be like reinventing the wheel...

Comment: I'm saying, download something like sqlYOG or another third party tool.  Try that and report back.

Comment: @bigman: well, I will do that, but this won't solve my phpMyAdmin problem I guess...

Comment: I can't use sqlYOG because my MySQL is only available from localhost. However I used adminer which works fine. Anyway the problem with phpMyAdmin still persists...

Comment: Any chance you can update your phpMyAdmin installation?

Answer (score 3):

phpMyAdmin dosn't allow you to browse empty tables. A big red cross over Browse on top tab or disabled. So if Browse is avilable in phpMyAdmin what is the problem. A few times I have browsed a table with only 1 record and I thought I was not getting a result. In my hurry I didn't realize there was a record showing. A 1 row record is easyly missed.

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thx for the answer, but it doesn't help a bit... :) My page stops after the column names and doesn't show any more... otherwise it looks the same. It is a strange problem and I just installed adminer which is a similar tool. It works perfect but is not so pretty but therefor a lot smaller.

Comment: I actually would have rated your answer as useful but my reputation is too low.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem in phpMyAdmin 3.5.4, nor in 4.0. The data should be visible if it's there.

Could you provide the table structure you used?

Anyway, you should update to some newer version, probably 4.0 or later. Feel free to report the issue on http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs

Comment: Thanks zixtor for the follow up. As mentioned above I have switched to adminer which does a wonderful job and it is very simple. The issue got resolved for me by switching to that other tool. I don't have any phpAdmin installation any more.